# Accessing certain elements of tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples, element

I have to solve a problem for university studies. So what I want basically is that I want to access certain elements two 2-tuples. I already defined a function:

```
taxiDistance :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
```

as you can see the function takes two 2-tuples containing integers and returns a integer.
And now I have to add the first elements of both tuples and 2nd of both. And I don't now how to access these values which were put in by a user before.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: if you're adding the first and second elements you're probably doing the computations wrong.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the functions [fst](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.17/base-4.11.1.0/Prelude.html#v:fst) + [snd](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.17/base-4.11.1.0/Prelude.html#v:snd) like this:

```
taxiDistance :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
taxiDistance x y = fst x + fst y
```

or alternatively you can deconstruct the tuples in the declaration like:

```
taxiDistance :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
taxiDistance (a,b) (c,d) = a + b + c + d
```

Comment: damn I ruthless just came out with the answer!! sorry :S

Comment: I think this is fine, I don't see how it's pedagogically helpful not to reveal the *syntax* of what they're trying to do.  There's nothing to "think through" here.

Comment: This is fine as it is. You didn't solve the full task of the OP: the OP also needs to compute the taxi distance, and that will involve a (slightly) more complex formula. Revealing "how to access the pair components" is perfectly OK, since you can find it on books anyway. What is usually frowned upon (IMO) is to answer a much more broad question dumping the full solution, without a careful explanation. Doing that would only allow the OP to copy&paste their homework, with no chance of actually learning anything. But you didn't do that :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is university studies I won't give the entire answer right away but will point you to read up on [pattern matching](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) and [tuple constructor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching#Tuple_constructors).